# Sum values in an array using 2D and 3D arrays

Tags: python, arrays

because i wasn't clear on my last question, i'm re-editing it :

Let's suppose an array

```
A = [[A[0][0], A[0][1], ..., A[0][10]],
     [A[1][0], A[1][1], ..., A[1][10]],  
     [............................],
     [A[1k][0], A[1k][1], ..., A[1k][10]],
     [A[1k+1][0], A[1k+1][1], ..., A[1k+1][10]],
     [A[1k+2][0], A[1k+2][1], ..., A[1k+2][10]],
     [.....................................],
     [A[2k][0], A[2k][1], ..., A[2k][10]],
     [A[2k+1][0], A[2k+1][1], ..., A[2k+1][10]],
     [.....................................],
     [A[nk][0], A[nk][0], ..., A[nk][10]]]
```

As an output, I'm trying to get :

```
B = [[A[0][0]+A[1k][0]+...+A[nk][0], A[0][1]+A[1k][1]+...+A[nk][1], ... , A[0][10]+A[1k][10]+...+A[nk][10]],
     [A[1][0]+b[1k+1][0]+...+A[nk+1][0], A[1][1]+A[1k+1][1]+...+A[nk+1][1], ... , A[1:10]+A[1k+1][10]+...+A[nk+1][10]],
     [.......................................................................................................], 
     [A[1k-1][0]+A[2k-1][0]+...+A[(n+1)k-1][1], A[1k-1][1]+A[2k-1][1]+...+A[(n+1)k-1][1], ... , A[1k-1][10]+A[2k-1][10]+...+A[(n+1)k-1][10]],
```

To resume, it is a sum of all first element of sub-array, in a new array.

I already tried this with a way smaller example :

```
data = [[1, 7],
        [2, 8],
        [3, 9],
        [4, 10],
        [5, 11],
        [6, 12],
        [13, 14],
        [15, 16]]
A= {}
m=2
A=[data[idx: idx + m] for idx in range(0, len(data), m)]
B=[]
for a in range(1,2) :
    for l in range(2):
        B.append([])
        for c in range(2):
            B[l].append(A[a][l][c]+A[a-1][l][c])
            print('B = ' + str(B))
print('end')
```

I'm trying to obtain :

```
B = [[1+3+5+13, 7+9+11+14],
     [2+4+6+15, 8+10+12+14]]
```

My example is quiet easy because it has a well-know number of row.

But i can't find a generic solution.
Plus, I don't really know how many n*1k row I got, but if I can find some solution at least for 2k row, i can improve it I guess.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello, yeah I totally mean a(0:0) the value in the first row & first column. Sould I edit all using the subscripting notation you gave me ?

Comment: Yes, you should clarify in the question.  If a is a 2d array, it's first row first column is a[0][0], first row, second column is a[0][1], r-th row, k-th column is a[r][k].

Comment: Ok then, thank you about that

Comment: @DarrylG I made few changes to make it cristal clear. I hope it still ok to understand

Comment: @NycoElm--now A is defined in turns of itself.  It may be simpler just to have A be an example small matrix with a given number of columns and values and show the desired output.

Comment: @DarrylG Okay, I'll complete my exemple above, to show what I want as output when the input is the data-array

Comment: @NycoElm--8+10+11+14 should be 8+10+12+16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create desired output as follows.

**Code**

```
def sum_data(data, rows_per_group):
    mt = list(zip(*data))            # Matrix transpose to allow summing 
                                     # over column element
                                     # (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transpose-matrix-single-line-python/
    
    # Use list comprehension to sum 
    return [[sum(p[offset::rows_per_group]) for p in mt] for offset in range(rows_per_group)]
```

Example Usage:

```
data = [[1, 7],
        [2, 8],
        [3, 9],
        [4, 10],
        [5, 11],
        [6, 12],
        [13, 14],
        [15, 16]]

print(sum_data(data, 2))

# Output:
[[22, 41], [27, 46]]
```

Comment: Okay thanks it seems to work. Can it be applied for 10 columns and n-row ? I'll say yes but I'm never sure as beginner

Comment: @NycoElm--I made it into a function so you can see how to apply to different data.  Does this help?

Comment: Not so sure about the variable ncolumns because i don't know where you used it, but i'll try to familiarise myself with this code

Comment: @NycoElm--you're right, I don't use  ncolumns so removed it.